# How to get multiple queries in single run

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For example I have a dataframe like below,

```
df
DataFrame[columnA: int, columnB: int]
```

If I have to do two checks. I am going over the data two times like below,

```
df.where(df.columnA == 412).count()
df.where(df.columnB == 25).count()
```

In normal code I would be having two count variable and incrementing on True. How would I go with spark dataframe? Appreciate if some one could link to right documentation also. Happy to see python or scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (412, 0),
  (0,   25), 
  (412, 25), 
  (0,   25)
)).toDF("columnA", "columnB")

df.agg(
  sum(($"columnA" === 412).cast("long")).alias("columnA"),
  sum(($"columnB" === 25).cast("long")).alias("columnB")
).show

// +-------+-------+
// |columnA|columnB|
// +-------+-------+
// |      2|      3|
// +-------+-------+
```

or like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{count, when}

df.agg(
  count(when($"columnA" === 412, $"columnA")).alias("columnA"),
  count(when($"columnB" === 25, $"columnB")).alias("columnB")
).show

// +-------+-------+
// |columnA|columnB|
// +-------+-------+
// |      2|      3|
// +-------+-------+
```

I am not aware of any specific documentation but I am pretty sure you'll find this in any good SQL reference.

Answer (score 2):

@zero323's answer is spot on, but just to indicate the most flexible programming model is Spark, you could do your checks as `if` statements inside a `map` with a lambda function, e.g. (using the same dataframe as above)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._  

val r1 = df.map(x => {
  var x0 = 0
  var x1 = 0
  if (x(0) == 412) x0=1
  if (x(1) == 25) x1=1
  (x0, x1)
}).toDF("x0", "x1").select(sum("x0"), sum("x1")).show()
```

This model lets you do almost anything you can think of, though you're much better off sticking with the specific APIs where available.

Comment: Thank you Ewan, for an great example. Wish SO allows to accept two answers.

Comment: No problem, the other answer is much better for this case :)